# How to find and replace data of file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

My filename is myfile.txt and i want to replace some data inside it using shell script.
I want to replace `ScriptPathPC=\Myfile\file_core` into `ScriptPathPC=./file_core/`
The code which i tried is

`replace "ScriptPathPC=\Myfile\file_core" "ScriptPathPC=./file_core/" -- myfile.txt`

But this command is working well with forward slash[/] and not with backward slash[]. Is there any other solution for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using replace

`replace` requires that the substitution be done perl-style:

```
replace 's|ScriptPathPC=\\Myfile\\file_core|ScriptPathPC=./file_core/|' file.txt
```

The substitute command looks like `s|old|new|`.  To prevent special treatment of them, we have to escape the backslashes.

#### Using sed

`sed` can similarly make changes.  Here, we display the new file on stdout:

```
$ sed 's|ScriptPathPC=\\Myfile\\file_core|ScriptPathPC=./file_core/|' myfile.txt 
ScriptPathPC=./file_core/
```

Here, we change the old file in place:

sed -i 's|ScriptPathPC=\Myfile\file_core|ScriptPathPC=./file_core/|' myfile.txt